# Data Points Within 4% of Best fit line algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphing-functions

This question is actually based on a problem I am attempting to solve within a C program.  I am attempting to understand how the mathmatical equation that would need to be writtne.

I will have 10 data points.  I know ahead of time what the X value for each of these points will be.  I have to calculate the value of the Y for each point.  I believe I have everything I need to calculate the best fit line.  My question isn't on how to calculate the best fit line itself.

The problem I have is that I need to verify that each data point is within **4%** of the line itself.  I won't actually be plotting the line itself, I believe each {X,Y} point of the best-fit line will need to be calcualte, to determine if my data points are within **4%** I just don't know the equation to do that.

**What is the equation?**

The follow graphics are for illustration purposes only.  I wasn't able to think of a best title for the question.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Image Source](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit.html)

Comment: Can you put what you mean by "each data point is within 4% of the line" into other words?  E.g. do you mean "the difference between the actual y value and the predicted y value will be at most 4% of the predicted y value"?

Comment: @oks - The 4% is based on a requirement dealing with some hardware.  We provide it input and recieve an output and calculate the best-fit line based on the data.  The requirements simply indicate that each output should be within 4% of the best-fit line.  The only way I know how to determine that is to calculate several data points ( at the very least the same number of data points I calculated ) of the line itself and verify the data points are within 4% of one another.  Does that make sense?  If it does I will update my question with that explination.

Comment: @Ramhound. I think that you properly described your problem. It is a classical one when you do regression work and you need to interpolate of even extrapolate. There are other much more sophisticated methods which define the confidence limits (this create two curves above and below the rgression line).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I didn't want to add to much detail or complexity to describe the problem.  I had one of those brain farts, I wasn't able visualize, how to calculate the difference between two points.  Your answer and explaination resolved that problem.

Comment: @Ramhound. I am glad to have helped you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have your original data points say [x(i),y(i)] and you have your model which, in ganeral manner write y = f[x]. So, for each value x(i), compute y_calc(i) = f[x(i)]. The difference [y_calc(i) - y(i)] is the absolute error and [y_calc(i) - y(i)] / y(i) is the relative error for data point (i). Check for each of the points this relative error (take its absolute value) is or not lower than 0.04.

Comment: I beieve this is what I need.  Let me verify it, and if it is, I plan to accept your answer.